# Why my random-discord module throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I installed `random-discord` module but when I want to use it, it doesn't work. I receive the following error:

```
(node:10278) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://apis.duncte123.me/meme reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Here is my code (I literally copied the documentation code):

```
const discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new discord.Client()
const { Random } = require("random-discord")
const random = new Random();
const config = require("./config.json");
 
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I'm Online")
})
 
client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.content === "!memes") {
    let data = await random.getMeme()
    message.channel.send(data)
  }
})
 
client.login(config.token)
```

Tell my if I must correct something.

Comment: This error generally happens when your endpoint sends HTML. It looks like yours is correctly sending JSON though. Can you try again or debug what's inside `data`?

Comment: Also make sure to try again, the website might have been under maintance when you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `random-discord` package uses the API at `https://apis.duncte123.me/meme`. While it returns with a JSON response from the browser, it returns a 503 error status from the backend when you don't set a user agent. Not sure if it was the case before or if it's a recent update but at the moment it only works if you set a `user-agent` header.

You don't really need to use that package though, as it only fetches the data from the API and puts it in an embed. You can do the same on your own with [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and by sending a custom `user-agent` in the request headers.

Check the snippet below:

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("I'm online");
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!memes') {
    const URL = 'https://apis.duncte123.me/meme';
    const headers = {
      'user-agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.152 Safari/537.36',
    };
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL, { headers });

      if (!response.ok)
        return message.reply("there was an error, can't reach the API.");

      const { data } = await response.json();
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(data.title)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setImage(data.image);
      message.channel.send(embed);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      message.reply('there was an error, no memes for you! Maybe try again?');
    }
  }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Don't forget that you need to install `node-fetch`. Run `npm i node-fetch` in your root folder.